# Add badge to angular prime ng split button dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, primeng

I try to add badge to a split button drop down, but the badge property does not seem to display, do I miss something?

as you can see it only displays icon, label but no badge number

```
 [![badge][1]][1]
```

template

```
     <p-splitButton label="Save" icon="fa-check" (onClick)="save()" 
      [model]="items"></p-splitButton>
```

ts

```
      items: MenuItem[];

         this.items = [
        {label: 'Update', icon: 'fa-refresh', badge: "23"}, //does not display badge number
                      ];
```

the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel) of MenuItem[] states that it has "badge" property. SplitButton [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/splitbutton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like its only supported on premium PrimeNG Themes